# MapStruct: Difference between BeanMapping and Mapping

Tags: java, mapping, javabeans, mapstruct

I have been going through the documentation of MapStruct and can't seem to figure out when the annotation `@BeanMapping` should be used. The documentation seems to extensively use just `@Mapping` for most cases as well. Could someone explain the use of `@BeanMapping` annotation? Perhaps with an example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `@Mapping` annotation is one of the core annotation of MapStruct. It allows you to define mappings between properties that are not named the same. From the JavaDoc:

> Configures the mapping of one bean attribute.

The `@BeanMapping` annotation is there to control the behaviour of the entire mapping method. You can use `@BeanMapping` to set the `NullValueCheckStrategy` for the entire mapping method. From the JavaDoc:

> Configures the mapping between two bean types

Answer (score 2):

simply @BeanMapping let you customize the mapping process.

example 1: @BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true) means No automatic mapping will take place, so All mappings have to be defined manually.

example 2: @BeanMapping(ignoreUnmappedSourceProperties = {"title"}) means ignore title field during the mapping process